# Facing issue with GCM push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my app, I've been using `GCM` for push notifications. Everything is working fine upto `Android Lollipop`.
That makes me think, there's no configuration or setup related error. Issue starts from `Android 6`, Somehow no push notifications are received on devices running 6 and above.

Do I need to specify some addition settings for let it work? Or Is there a work around for this problem?

**What I've tried?**

1. I've manually configure the whitelist in `Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization`.
2. Also tried adding `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`
3. Basic: `reboot` device , clean `cache` and all.
4. Gone through almost all the related ques/answers over `SO`, but apparently none worked.
5. Updated my `GCM` compile `dependencies` to latest versions.
6. Tried on various devices with different `OS` versions.

*I know `GCM` is now out-dated by `FCM`, but due to some project dependencies, I'm forced to use `GCM`*

Any sort of help would be highly appreciate.:)

**Update** 
This is how I've generated notification :

```
    int icon = R.drawable.app_icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, displayClass);
    intent.putExtra("from", "Notification");
    intent.putExtra("xx", xx);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), icon);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText("some text")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setAutoCancel(true).setLargeIcon(image).setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(message).setWhen(when).setColor(Color.WHITE);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(myNotificationId, builder.build());
```

Comment: how you are creating Notification Object ?

Comment: Is there any significant difference in creating Notification Objects for different OS? @MFaheemRajput

Comment: well is your notification icon appears in top status bar ?

Comment: No notification ( including icon or anything ) appears neither in status bar nor in menu

Comment: Then system is not creating your notification.

Comment: let me see how you making notification object

Comment: @MFaheemRajput Updated, please check.

Comment: please check if you are using any deprecated api for android 6 and above